# Updating Unbound combo box value lists

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have a database that allows an end user to search all available records in a table based on the criteria they have entered. I have a form with three command buttons (search, clear, and close), six unbound text or combo boxes, and a query. When the user enters data into the text or combo boxes they will click the search button and the query will use the users data to search the table for the results. All of this works great. My problem is…. The combo boxes are value lists. When I add new values to the list, all bound fields update automatically, but the unbound do not. Is there a way for me to automatically update those unbound fields when I update the bound ones too? My code for the search button is below if anyone has any pointers or thinks something needs changed.

The record source for the bound comboboxes is empty but has a control source from the table (manufacturer combo's control source is the manufacturer field of the table and the main form is bound to the table). The Unbound combo box has a value list record source and the form is unbound. If I bind the form to the table and the control source of the combo to the correct field of the table When I select a manufacturer as my search criteria it changes the records to that manufacturer instead of just finding all the records that match the criteria.

```
If DCount("*", "User Customer Owned Parts Query") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Records Found"
    Else
        Me.User_Customer_Owned_Parts_Query_Subform.Requery
End If
```

Comment: *How* do you add new values to the list(s)? What bound fields (the result list?) ? -- You can always do `Me.myCombobox.Requery`, but your post isn't very clear about what you are actually doing.

Comment: The combo boxes value lists allow edits. So as a new product comes in I (Admin) am able to edit the list to add the new product. This updates all the bound fields (There are several forms that have combo boxes that are bound to the table field). I have a search form with unbound combo boxes. I would like to have the unbound combo boxes be updated with the new product that was added to the value list when it is added.

Comment: Still not clear, but we'll get there. What is the `RowSource` of the bound comboboxes, and what is it for the unbound comboboxes? Please edit your question with the info, comments are not really suited for these explanations.

Comment: Perhaps store the options for these combo boxes in a table of their own and then use that as the row source for your combo boxes. If there are new options to add to the list you can either just add it to options table manually or try one of these fancy methods: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-27.html

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea. Thanks I will give that a try.